# __doPostBack not working inside GridView DropDownList

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

As topic , I have a item template than consist of a dropdownlist , when user attempt to click it , warning should come out to warn User whether to continue or not. after I click OK , nothing happens , it is not going back to the postback

My gridview code for item template is like the following :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">                
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>                
</asp:TemplateField>
```

My Code behind will set the JavaScript to the attribute

```
DropDownList cboStatus= (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("cboStatus");
cboStatus.Attributes.Add("onChange",  "Confirmation();");
```

JavaScript :

```
function Confirmation() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?')) {
        __doPostback(this, 'Select${0}');
    }
}
```

I want my postback to call this function

```
protected void cboStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Some Code
}
```

Comment: take a look to how to __doPostback(this, 'Select${0}'); is renderized

Comment: hi @wintermute what do you mean ?

Comment: Try to use OnSelectedIndexChanged instead of onChange.

Comment: Where are you asigning the `cboStatus_Click` handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code a bit like below. This has been tested locally to be working fine. The below code will fire up the server event for selection changed if `Ok` from the confirmation window is clicked otherwise not.

Your gridview template definition

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">                
   <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onchange="return Confirmation ();" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboStatus_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>                
</asp:TemplateField>
```

JavaScript function for the `onchange` event

```
function Confirmation() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?')) {
        __doPostBack('__Page', '');
    }
    return false;
}
```

And finally your server event for `SelectedIndexChanged`

```
 protected void cboStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      // Some code
 }
```

Comment: Hi , @Dennis R by add OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" eventhough I press cancel it still fire cboStatus_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: @abccba It does work for me correctly. I've edited the code for `function Confirmation()` with just a `return false;` after the `if` statement. Try it if it helps. Also make sure your `cboStatus` has `onchange="return Confirmation ();"` attached and you have removed the `onChange` event you were attaching in your original code through code behind.

Comment: thanks for your effort , it works , but I have discover a minor problem which is whenever a CANCEL is pressed , the next click for OK , will not fire the postback , do you know what problem causing it ?